# sql sum rows and put into columns of select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that essentially has:

```
person  activity-code  activity-value
```

There are multiple activity-codes (about 17 of them) and activity-values per person. For exmaple:

```
A  1   10
A  1   12
A  2   4
B  1   5
B  2   3
B  2   8
```

What I want is a select statement that returns something like:

```
A   22 4
B   5  11
```

So the *first column* is the `person`.  The *second column* is the sum of all `activity-values for the activity-code 1` for that person.  The *third column* is the sum of all `activity-values for the activity-code 2` for that person.  etc...

In the end I want to do this and use the OUTFILE command in there as I want to dump the totals to a file to be imported into an excel file.

It seems like there is a subquery in there somewhere but I am not advanced enough to figure that out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can add detail if that is going to help.

Comment: It looks like: 


    SELECT *, SUM(CASE when `Activity ID`=1 then Value end) total1, SUM(CASE when `Activity ID`=2 then Value end) total2, SUM(CASE when `Activity ID`=3 then Value end) total3 FROM `Activities` WHERE ...


is what I want, but I don't really want to type in the SUM(CASE... end) 17 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, Mysql lacks the `pivot` command present in other databases, which makes this sort of thing a piece of cake. You're stuck with something like

```
 select
      person,
      sum(case activitycode when 1 then activityvalue else 0 end),
      sum(case activitycode when 2 then activityvalue else 0 end),
      ....
 from 
      yourtable
 group by
      person
```

Comment: `+1` for you buddy! by the way, what sql formatter you are using? :D